# unlink function is not working

Tags: php

I'm using the following code.

```
     $un=@unlink('/var/www/vhosts/mtsbeta.com/httpdocs/beta/cache_files/cache.php');
    print_r($unlink);
    @session_destroy();
    //exit;
    $host1=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header("location:https://$host1/index.php?msg=2");
```

if I used the exit it is working.please let me know why it is not working?

Comment: Maybe your index regenerates the cache.php?

Comment: What isn't working?  The `header` *won't* work because you are `print_r`ing before it.

Comment: unlink function is not working .header is working

Comment: Try removing the `@` before `unlink`.  If you are trying to debug a script, hiding the errors isn't going to help.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@` so that you can see *why*?

Comment: I removed the @ it is not working.if I put the exit and refresh the page then it is working why?

Answer (score 9):

lots of issues in the posted code:

```
@unlink('/var/www/vhosts/mtsbeta.com/httpdocs/beta/cache_files/cache.php');
```

--Remove the @ symbol as the others suggested, it will throw the error message

```
print_r($unlink);
```

-- There is no variable called `$unlink` in the code. What you have is `$un` Also the return value of `unlink()` is either `true` or `false`, not an array. So when you do a `print_r`, you either get 1 (in case of true/unlink success) or nothing at all (in case of false/unlink failure) - and this might even further confuse you.

```
header("location:https://$host1/index.php?msg=2");
```

-- you are already doing a `print_r`. If anything has been outputted into the page, then header wont work

I know this is not an answer to the OP question, but I think considering there are at least three desired changes in five lines of working code, maybe tweak the code a bit more before getting into the issue with the unlink not working?

Comment: i removed the @ it is not working not showing the any error and it redirecting the page to the index.php

Comment: There can be a bunch of things. First, how are you determining that the file is not getting deleted? are you checking its location physically? what process created the file? does your process have write permission over it?

First thing to do is to comment out the header() and start debugging. We are in no hurry to jump to another page before we are sure the file has been deleted, right? :)